# How to detect a no network error in AngularFire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am building an app with Angular 7, Firebase and [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). I want to detect a no network error occurring when trying to perform CRUD operations with Firestore.

At first I was thinking that I can use something like an `HttpInterceptor` and do the following:

```
if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
    return throwError(new NoNetworkConnectionError('No network connection'));
} else {
    return next.handle(request);
}
```

Then, I thought, I can catch the error in a `try-catch` block and determine whether it is an instance of my custom `NoNetworkConnectionError` type. However, it didn't work, because I can't really intercept the calls that AngularFire2 is making with an HttpInterceptor, so I am pretty much stuck.

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE:**
I am not trying to check whether Firestore is online or not, but whether the user has Internet connection or not. If it was a simple HTTP request done with the `HttpClient` in Angular, that could be solved by following the above steps. However, the HTTP requests that perform the CRUD operations in Firestore happen within the `AngularFire2` library and I can't come up with a way to capture this. So, if I try to do something with Firestore, while my Internet is off, I cannot catch this error, I am just getting

> POST https ://firestore.googleapis.com/...net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Comment: is it simply a re-throw from angular fire, no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect firestore connection failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093039/how-to-detect-firestore-connection-failure)