# Firestore for web - on offline write, throw rather than save locally & sync on connection restore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As far as I understand, Firestore, by default, works in such a way that if a write is made, but the client is offline, the write is stored locally, then sent to the server once the connection's restored.

It's an undesired behaviour for me, since:

- I've got an app that stores some data.
- Multiple users can update the same data.
- As far as I understand, if user A stores a local write due to network errors, then user B makes some changes, then user A gets his connection back running, then user's A write will overwrite user's B changes.

**Therefore, I'd like to completely disable the offline features. If a write directly to the servers could not be completed for whatever reason, I'd like to have an error thrown,** or be signaled in any other way, so I can simply inform the user. **How do I do that?**

My current code:

```js
    firestore
      .collection("someData")
      .doc(props.id)
      .set({ contentState: content }, { merge: true })
      .catch(x => {
        console.log("Error!");
        setSyncError(true);
      });
```

The catch func never fires, I assume it's because the buffer-offline-writes capability is enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention "Firestore for web" in your question's title.

Note that for the web, **offline persistence is disabled by default**, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> When you initialize Cloud Firestore, you can enable or disable offline
>   persistence:
>
> - For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default. To disable persistence, set the PersistenceEnabled option to false.
> - For the web, offline persistence is disabled by default. To enable persistence, call the enablePersistence method. Cloud Firestore's
>     cache isn't automatically cleared between sessions. Consequently, if
>     your web app handles sensitive information, make sure to ask the user
>     if they're on a trusted device before enabling persistence.

---

For the case when there is no connection between your browser and the Firestore "backend"/service, please see the following Stack Overflow Q/A: [How to detect firestore connection failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093039/how-to-detect-firestore-connection-failure)

Comment: From the linked response: "A write that involves a transaction can't be written to local cache - it must be performed while fully online." I've implemented the write as a transaction. Works well.

Comment: That's a smart use of a transaction! :-)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I don't know If I should post another question - but is this the best answer to this problem? I have the same use case, nothing has changed with this setting. If cache is false, I can still delete/write locally on my app/Flutter. The only two solutions seem to be using a transaction or an onCall to make sure the client is online and guarente the changes are in sync with both parties.