# Check if firestore is reachable (Internet is available and server is online)

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, connection

This is a very very odd and confusing situation:

**What do we do:**
We check if we are connected to the internet by checking wifi and mobile connection state on the phone (This should be enough as offline persistence is enabled anyway for our project and we just want to display a hint to the user)

**What is the problem**
Now it gets VERY suspicious. One of the internet providers in Germany send routers to the users that are UNABLE to connect to espacially firebase/firestore servers. This happend to at least 3 different persons that own that special router. The provider told me there is no port blocking and no other restriction. There are just routers that won't connect for whatever reason. This also means that internet works but the data will never gets synchronized while the user uses wifi.

Also the enduser cannot access any portblocking/portforwarding feature. All manages by the provider. I had to request a new router 4 times until I got one that allowed access to the server. And now when I test the app at a friends place - same issue. No connection until wifi is disabled - Same provider, same router and the provider of course says there is no known issue.

**The question**
Is there a way to check if the connection to firebase is established (Maybe pinging the IP of firestore? Which one is it?) Or is there maybe a method providing exactly that kind of information

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093039/how-to-detect-firestore-connection-failure

Comment: I saw this. So this is why I asked about ping the IP

Comment: The IP address is solved via DNS resolution, so you should be able to ping Firestore via the url you use to establish the connection in your code... but I have an inkling that this is an ISP issue, just that whomever you contacted wasn't informed of the decision (customer service/support usually doesn't have access to specs/architecture) - so it's entirely possible that they're identifying Firestore as a liability to security or something of the sort. It's likely not port-blocking, but it could be IP-blocking or some other security feature., I'd try calling them again.

Comment: If they really would block firestore they would effectivly render so many apps useless as they all rely on firestore. I got other routers from the same ISP and the issue is gone. If you have a fritzBox the issue is gone. It is a problem with the cheap china made routers they supply free of charge as a rental to their customers. As per the URL, that is internal. I do not have the IP/url that firestore is connecting internally